Type hint for an object that can be used as a type hint itself
I have following code
from typing import TypeVar, Type, overload

T = TypeVar('T')


@overload
def foo(bar: Type[T]) -> T:
    ...

@overload
def foo(bar: Type[T] | None) -> T | None:
    ...


def foo(bar: Type[T] | None) -> T | None:
    # implementation goes here
    ...


class Bar:
    ...


bar = foo(Bar)
bar2 = foo(Bar | None)  # No overload variant of "foo" matches argument type "UnionType"

How to properly type hint case for bar2?

I tried some others:
Type[T | None], mypy says Overloaded function signature 2 will never be matched: signature 1's parameter type(s) are the same or broader
removing 2nd overload (resulting in only Type[T] allowed), mypy says No overload variant of "foo" matches argument type "UnionType" (meaning 2nd overload is incorrect for that case anyways)

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here exactly. Type[T] | None is a type hint. Bar | None is also a type hint. Why are you trying to pass a type hint as argument to a function? The type hint Type[T] | None means either a type or the value None may be passed, so valid calls would be foo(Bar) and foo(None). What are you trying to accomplish with foo(Bar | None)?

@deceze I want to parse some optional result (I pass the type directly to pydantic.TypeAdapter) inside foo, so it returns T | None. It works ok, but I can't type annotate that sadly. I think I'll stick to optional=False kwarg then:/

Only concrete classes are assignable to type[T]:

[...] the actual argument passed in at runtime must [...] be a concrete class object [...]
— Special types in annotations § type[] | Python typing spec

(Admittedly, the spec isn't completely clear about this. However, the following paragraph holds true.)
It is thus understood that an object of this type can be invoked to retrieve an instance of type T. type[T] | None means such a thing, or None; thus, bar might or might not be invocable.
def foo(bar: type[T] | None) -> None:
    if bar is not None:
        reveal_type(bar)  # type[T]
        instance = bar()  # fine

However, Bar | None returns an instance of UnionType at runtime, and objects of this kind cannot be invoked.
foo(Bar | None)       # (Bar | None) is not None
                      # bar() => error

What you want is the proposed TypeForm of PEP 747 (a draft PEP):
def foo[T](bar: TypeForm[T]) -> T: ...

reveal_type(foo(Bar | None))  # Bar | None


Yes, that was the thing I wanted. Sad that it's only draft:(
